# Программа для рисования SVG изображений

Tags: css, windows, svg, macos, поиск-программ

Всем привет. Посоветуйте в какой программе или сервисе сейчас лучше всего рисовать svg?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133684/discussion-on-question-by-saniate----svg-).

Answer (score 7):

Notepad++ или любой текстовый редактор, который подсвечивает синтаксис XML; Inkscape; Adobe Illustrator  и вот ещё подборка других векторных редакторов, онлайн генераторов, оптимизаторов SVG, которые заметно упрощают создание SVG изображений:
[Какие программы и генераторы можно применять для облегчения написания кода svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/925990/28748)

*ОК, svg нарисован в векторном редакторе, но что-то не устраивает, что-то хочется изменить, понять в конце концов, что означают эти цифры и буквы*

### Учебные материалы здесь, на ru.stackoverflow.com

1. [Книги и учебные материалы по SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/784137/28748)

---

2. [Как правильно написать формулу path](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/831351/28748)

Приведены примеры различных вариантов синтаксиса написания `path` для самых простейших фигур SVG

---

3. [Префикс не связан c пространством имён SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782166/28748)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

4. [Поиск ошибок в приложениях SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/825532/28748)

В статье рассматриваются наиболее часто возникающие ошибки при написании кода SVG и примеры их устранения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

5. [Как взаимодействуют между собой viewport и viewBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748)

Отвечает на вопросы с чем связано масштабирование, адаптивность. А также на вопросы, почему исчезает, обрезается изображение SVG, почему возникают большие отступы у изображения

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, на 2022 г. в мире не существует графического редактора, который мог бы работать с SVG-исходником в реальном времени. Т.е. чтобы редактировать сложный SVG-файл (карту, схему) можно было одновременно и как текст (id, классы, стили, точные значения координат), и как векторное изображение, без потери данных.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov Спасибо за вопрос, он очень актуальный для людей начинающих изучать и работающих с SVG. Но он настолько широк, что ответить на него подробно в комментариях затруднительно. **У меня к вам предложение**, - задайте отдельный вопрос по мотивам вашего комментария. Мне было бы интересно ответить на него.

Comment: Nodepad++ то каким боком?))) Тогда и любой другой текстовый редактор, но я думаю, что это немного не о том редакторы в данном случае.

Comment: @Leonid В принципе согласен, любой текстовый редактор, который подсвечивает синтаксис XML

Comment: Это какой-то мета-ответ на какой-то мета-вопрос (который здесь даже не задан, автор ни о чём подобном не спрашивал). Я сильно сомневаюсь, что подобное вписывается в формат базы знаний.

Comment: @andreymal Долго в ping-pong будем играть? Иди... на мету, организуй тему. Ты же любишь покрасоваться на мете, сам же об этом говорил

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо, я решился сформулировать [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1380348/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-svg-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2]) (на примере собственной боли)

Comment: @Alexey Vladimirov Спасибо, я прочитал ваш вопрос, Надеюсь вы понимаете, что быстро на него ответить оч. затруднительно

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да, я понимаю, что лучше всего мне самому же и ответить на него со временем