# Как визуально редактировать большой SVG, без потери классов и атрибутов элементов?

Tags: css, svg, illustrator

#### TL;DR

> При редактировании SVG > Illustrator > SVG теряются исходные классы элементов. Как можно безопасно визуально редактировать большой svg-файл?

**Уточнение после первого ответа:** Inkscape для masOS просто не тянет большой проект, см. UPD2

---

**Предыстория.** Меня увлекла идея геосервиса в миниатюре — на базе одного svg-файла. Это интерактивная «тепловая карта» исторического центра города с цветовым кодированием архитектурной ценности зданий и прочими визуальными спецэффектами, не всегда доступными,  например, в API Google Maps. Так, уже удалось: конвертировать топоснову в проекции Меркатора из OpenStreetMap в SVG с привязкой вьюбокса к геокоординатам; связать полигоны зданий с адресным справочником, данными об этажности и годах постройки; добиться приемлемой производительности масштабирования и прокрутки (спасибо, [D3.js](https://d3js.org/))

**Как я представлял себе работу c SVG.** Параллельные процессы:

1. *Визуальная корректировка геометрии в Adobe Illustrator:* исправление топографических ошибок, комбинирование полигонов в единые объекты (здания с внутренними дворами) и т.д.
2. *Работа по визуализации данных средствами JavaScript и CSS в консоли Chrome.* Добавление полигонам множественных классов, либо data-атрибутов, отвечающих за визуальное представление.
   Пример: `<polygon class="bld bld-type-public bld-age-soviet bld-style-constructivism" data-storeys="4" data-year="1927" id="b5270" points="2427,788 2435,786 2436,790 2433,791 2428,792"></polygon>` — используя различные селекторы и правила в таблице стилей, можно создать вокруг полигона свечение определенного размера, яркости и оттенка, в соответствии с типом, этажностью и эпохой постройки здания.

Т.е. процесс итерационный, и векторное изображение требует периодической корректировки, параллельно с DOM-манипуляциями на основе собираемых данных.

**Столкновение с реальностью.** Adobe Illustrator, являясь мощнейшим инструментом для редактирования сложных векторных изображений, лишь частично преобразует DOM svg-файла в собственную объектную модель. При моем подходе, часть данных безвозвратно теряется после редактирования SVG в Иллюстраторе.

| Данные | После редактирования в Adobe Illustrator |
| --- | --- |
| Координаты точек | ✅ Сохраняются как в исходном SVG |
| Группировка элементов (`<g>`) | ✅ Сохраняется (структура доступна в панели Layers) |
| ID элементов | ✅ Сохраняются (доступны как названия объектов в панели Layers) |
| Классы элементов | ❌ Теряются (любой список классов заменяется одним типовым именем) |
| Произвольные (data-) атрибуты элементов | ❌ Теряются |

#### Что делать?

Все эксперименты проводились на Adobe Illustrator CC 2019. Новейшие обновления не ставятся на мою macOS Mojave. Вряд ли что-то обновилось в работе с SVG (или ошибаюсь?).

- Есть ли кандидаты на место Illustrator в этом проекте?
- Существуют ли (внезапно) какие-нибудь продукты, расширяющие обычный функционал DevTools — для визуального редактирования SVG в браузере?

Безусловно, всегда остается вариант «постпроцессинга» после каждого редактирования в Иллюстраторе: по ID можно восстановить список классов и/или атрибутов из внешнего массива данных (JSON). Но очень не хотелось бы усложнять процесс, и без того отдающий безумием.

P.S. Моя благодарность Alexandr_TT за персональное предложение задать здесь этот вопрос.

Р.P.S. [Английская версия](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071213/how-do-i-visually-edit-svg-without-losing-classes-and-attributes) данного вопроса была закрыта — модератор расценил его как запрос software recommendations, что не соответствует гайдам. (Уже открыта, после поправки в формулировке вопроса. Спасибо за поддержку.)

**UPD. Минимальный тестовый SVG-код:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 640 200" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
        .test {fill:red;}
        .test.blue {fill:blue;}
    </style>
    <g>
        <rect id="item1" data-test="1" x="190" y="20" class="test" width="120" height="120"/>
        <rect id="item2" data-test="1" x="322" y="20" class="test blue" width="120" height="120"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Результат сохранения в Иллюстраторе (объединение/переименование классов, удаление атрибутов):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 640 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 640 200;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FF0000;}
    .st1{fill:#0000FF;}
</style>
<g>
    <rect id="item1" x="190" y="20" class="st0" width="120" height="120"/>
    <rect id="item2" x="322" y="20" class="st1" width="120" height="120"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

**UPD2. Тест Inkscape**

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/ru/) показал себя практически безупречно, с точки зрения сохранности данных: классы и data-атрибуты остаются на месте после сохранения. Более того, SVG — нативный рабочий формат и можно пользоваться встроенным XML-редактором. Но плата за это — очень слабая производительность. По крайней мере, в версии для macOS с моим проектом, который «летает» в Иллюстраторе, невозможно работать в linkscape. В связи с этим, мой прикладной **вопрос остаётся открытым**.

Ссылка на боевой тестовый файл для оценки производительности редактора: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/SeDt3B-9xdosPw (ок. 6Мб)

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить в вопрос фрагмент кода, чтобы конкретно с ним поиграть в различных векторных редакторах. Для начала посмотрите вот этот список векторных редакторов, может один из них не удаляет классы  [Какие программы и генераторы можно применять для облегчения написания кода svg] (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/925915/28748)

Comment: объединяй в группы или defs и помечай их id. Или можешь необходимые данные запихивать в <text> после элемента и оттуда их потом забирать.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT добавил минимальную тестовую болванку для демонстрации проблемы

Comment: @VladykoD я же не могу один полигон поместить сразу в несколько групп, чтобы классифицировать его по произвольному количеству признаков. Набор классов элемента — это и есть данные для быстрой визуализации в браузере. Хочется их сохранить при визуальном редактировании.

Comment: @Alexey Vladimirov Добавил [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1383552/28748)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> При моем подходе, часть данных безвозвратно теряется после
> редактирования SVG в Иллюстраторе.

*В данном ответе проверяется сохранение данных: имена классов, data-атрибутов при сохранении, редактировании SVG  файлов в векторном редакторе Inkscape*

### 1. На этом этапе проверяется загрузка, сохранение файла без редактирования

1.1 Тестовый файл из вопроса:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 640 200" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
        .test {fill:red;}
        .test.blue {fill:blue;}
    </style>
    <g>
        <rect id="item1" data-test="1" x="190" y="20" class="test" width="120" height="120"/>
        <rect id="item2" data-test="1" x="322" y="20" class="test blue" width="120" height="120"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

1.2 Сохранение файла в Inkscape (*.svg)

Выбираете файл / Сохранить как / в модальном окне в графе ***Тип файла:*** нажимаете галочку (красная стрелка на рисунке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В выпадающем списке выбираете: *Оптимизированный SVG (*.svg)*

Результат:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   id="Layer_1"
   x="0px"
   y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 640 200"
   xml:space="preserve"
   sodipodi:docname="test-ink-menu-opt.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)"><metadata
   id="metadata13"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
       rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
         rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:title></dc:title></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
   id="defs11" /><sodipodi:namedview
   pagecolor="#ffffff"
   bordercolor="#666666"
   borderopacity="1"
   objecttolerance="10"
   gridtolerance="10"
   guidetolerance="10"
   inkscape:pageopacity="0"
   inkscape:pageshadow="2"
   inkscape:window-width="1400"
   inkscape:window-height="987"
   id="namedview9"
   showgrid="false"
   inkscape:zoom="0.6390625"
   inkscape:cx="265.23228"
   inkscape:cy="100"
   inkscape:window-x="-8"
   inkscape:window-y="-8"
   inkscape:window-maximized="1"
   inkscape:current-layer="Layer_1" />
    <style
   type="text/css"
   id="style2">
        .test {fill:red;}
        .test.blue {fill:blue;}
    </style>
    <g
   id="g6">
        <rect
   id="item1"
   data-test="1"
   x="190"
   y="20"
   class="test"
   width="120"
   height="120" />
        <rect
   id="item2"
   data-test="1"
   x="322"
   y="20"
   class="test blue"
   width="120"
   height="120" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

*Как  можно увидеть все классы и data-attribute сохранились.*

1.3 Оптимизация файла SVG после Inkscape

Лишнюю служебную информацию можно убрать с помощью: [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 640 200" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css" id="style2">
    .test{fill:red}.test.blue{fill:#00f}
  </style>
  <g id="g6">
    <path id="item1" data-test="1" class="test" d="M190 20h120v120H190z"/>
    <path id="item2" data-test="1" class="test blue" d="M322 20h120v120H322z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

*Что изменилось?*
Классы, произвольные (data-) атрибуты элементов остались без изменения.
`<rect>` были преобразованы в `<path>` и это всё по делу, так как координаты, фигуры не изменились (те же прямоугольники), но многие команды svg работают только с `path`
Например: `textPath`, `animateMotion`

### 2. Добавление, редактирование элементов

2.1 Добавляем в Inkscape новый элемент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*SVG код после добавления элемента:*

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 640 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    .test{fill:red}.test.blue{fill:#00f}
  </style>
  <path class="test" data-test="1" d="M190 20h120v120H190z"/>
  <path class="test blue" data-test="1" d="M322 20h120v120H322z"/>
       <!-- Зелёный прмоугольник -->
  <path d="M61 20h116v120H61z" fill="#8dec24" stroke="#000"/>
</svg>
```

Для нового элемента добавляем вручную: `class="test green" data-test="1"`

*2.2 Редактируем: изменяем размеры элементов, положение их на холсте SVG*

Для чистоты эксперимента файл svg с тремя элементами и добавленным классом и атрибутом снова загружаем в редактор.

Затем меняем размеры, перемещаем элементы в редакторе

2.3 Файл svg оптимизированный на выходе:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 640 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <style>.test{fill:red}.test.blue{fill:#00f}.test.green{fill:#8dec24}</style>
 <path class="test" d="m174 94h104v90h-104z" fill="#f00" data-test="1"/>
 <path class="test blue" d="m322 4h127v136h-127z" fill="#00f" data-test="1"/>
 <path class="test green" d="m64 33h71v66h-71z" fill="#8dec24" stroke="#000" data-test="1"/>
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Что изменилось?*

Классы, date-attribute остались без изменения, но редактор добавил в тело `path` атрибуты представления SVG `fill="#f00"` `fill="#00f"` хотя стили были в CSS
`<style>.test{fill:red}.test.blue{fill:#00f}.test.green{fill:#8dec24}</style>`

Это произошло, потому что стили представления, внешние стили CSS, стили инлайн CSS, computed style имеют разный вес и что сработает в определенном конкретном случае, особенно когда появляется shadow DOM при клонировании, неизвестно. Поэтому разработчики векторного редактора и добавляют лишние стили.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее о иерархии стилей [тут](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/) и [тут](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/)

### Выводы:

1. Классы и date-attribute, которые вносятся вручную Inkscape не удаляет, не переименовывает при редактировании
2. Элементов, у которых нет ID в исходнике SVG, могут быть добавлены векторным редактором.
3. Могут быть добавлены лишние стили. Чтобы не путаться, не устраивать соревнования, лучше хранить их в одном месте. Либо в CSS, либо в SVG
4. Фильтры, градиенты, clip-path, mask, анимации тоже делать чисто либо SVG, либо CSS Так как одновременное их использование css и svg приводит к непредсказуемым последствиям.

Comment: Как раз параллельно установил и разбирался с Inkscape, он прекрасен по своей задумке: для него SVG — базовый формат, там есть XML-редактор через который видно классы и атрибуты в процессе редактирования. Но цена такой совместимости с SVG — на порядок более низкая производительность по сравнению с Иллюстратором. С моим рабочим файлом (ок. 6 Мб) продуктивная работа в версии для macOS становиться просто невозможной :((

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov вот ещё возникла идея: заменить date- атрибуты переменными CSS, у них наивысший приоритет и они перебьют все стили SVG и можно не заботиться об иерархии при добавлении эффектов из внешней таблицы стилей. К тому же попробуйте, может иллюстратор не будет удалять переменные css (var) при редактировании. Мне кажется я ответил на ваш вопрос по удалению классов и атрибутов. Хорошо бы принять ответ. И задать следующий конкретный вопрос в новом топике.

Comment: Да, ответ можно принять, он помогает решить задачу в исходной формулировке, в общем случае, что и требуется от SO. Тем не менее, я бы хотел оставить его еще не неделю в формате конкурса, чтобы попытаться решить свою узкоприкладную задачу с производительностью. Вряди ли, конечно, кто-то еще выступит с ответом, но и создавать новый вопрос нет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Окей, если data-атрибуты и классы теряются, а id - нет, почему бы не закодировать их через id?

Проходимся по XML-дереву, если там есть класс или data-аттрибуты, сериализируем их, например в json, потом кодируем в base64 чтоб не было запрещенных символов и кладем в поле id. Туда же, при необходимости, сохраняем оригинальный id.

После редактирования файла - заменяем назад.

---

Так же, в качестве альтернативы, можно сохранять эти данные не в id, а в внешний файл, а потом подставлять назад.

Comment: Да, в самом тексте вопроса изначально был упомянут такой вариант выхода из положения. Всю текущую классификацию объектов можно сохранить в JSON-массив перед редактированием векторов в Иллюстраторе. Затем, после правок геометрии, снова восстановить по id. И так каждый раз. Собственно, вопрос как раз для того, чтобы убедиться в отсутствии более простых решений.

Answer (score 1):

*Данный ответ не является конкурсным, так как не решает проблему сохранения `data-attr`

Но может оказаться полезным, в случае возникновения необходимости значительного сокращения размеров  файлов SVG.*

### Оптимизация, сокращение размера SVG файла

> Ссылка на боевой тестовый файл для оценки производительности
> редактора: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/SeDt3B-9xdosPw (ок. 6Мб)

***Первый этап***

Оптимизируем файл SVG с помощью:  [SVGO v2.6.1](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

На этом этапе оптимизатор убирает лишние пробелы между строками, а также количество знаков в дробной части цифр координат. Устанавливаем в настройкаx `SVGOMG`  один знак после десятичной точки. см. скрин ниже.
Можно убрать совсем дробную часть, но тогда могут возникнуть артефакты, искажения форм svg фигур. Тут надо смотреть конкретно сколько оставлять цифр после десятичной точки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Размер файла сократился до 4.2Mb и на 14k строк*

[Оптимизированный файл SVG](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/G47_8CcbMeayxA)

***Второй этап***

[SVGZ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG#SVGZ)

> Поскольку код SVG занимает довольно много места, была создана
> «обёртка» SVGZ, когда SVG сжимают с помощью gzip, а полученному файлу
> присваивают расширение «.svgz».
>
> SVG хорошо сжимается, поскольку это текстовый XML-документ, имеющий
> регулярную структуру.

Сжатие SVG в SVGZ поддерживают многие векторные редакторы: Adobe GoLive, Adobe Illustrator, CorelDRAW, Inkscape, Sketch только для macOS.

Для этих целей есть и онлайн редакторы, я выбрал для тестирования [ASPOSE](https://products.aspose.app/imaging/ru/image-compress/svg) - работает медленно с большими файлами, но сжимает хорошо.  В нашем случае:  с 4Mb до 1.2Mb

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Сжатый SVGZ файл -1.2Mb](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/mD_kjDTL_LMCiQ)

***Третий этап***

Открываем файл в Inkscape, конвертируем обратно в SVG, редактируем, сохраняем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И тут выясняется, что data-attr исчезли.
Это произошло на этапе сжатия в SVGZ формат. Так как data-attr не принадлежат пространству имен SVG, поэтому  как лишнее были удалены при конвертации.

### Вывод:

Отрицательный результат,- это тоже полезный результат. По крайне мере стало известно, что файл SVG можно сильно уменьшить в размерах, но всё что не принадлежит namespace SVG,- будет удалено при конвертации.

Comment: Суперблагодарен за помощь и интерес к проблеме. Сократить размер файла = время загрузки карты — важно само по себе. Насколько я вижу, на первом шаге сжатие достигается, прежде всего, за счет конвертации элементов <polygon> в элементы <path>, где вместо абсолютных координат всех точек используются относительные команды рисования линий. Как правило, запись получается короче, круто.

Comment: На втором шаге примера, при сжатии в SVGZ, в файле потерялись оригинальные id элементов — даже если бы мета-данные были не в data-атрибутах, а где-то в JSON, привязанные к id, то связь с ними бы потерялась. Но это вопрос не к формату, а к редактору. Иллюстратор сохраняет в svgz с оригинальными id. Правда, Хром не захотел показывать ни тот, ни другой svgz (Encoding error)

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov  `Правда, Хром не захотел показывать ни тот, ни другой svgz (Encoding error)` потому что SVGZ это уже **зазипованный растровый** формат. Попробуйте открыть его любым текстовым редактором и увидите крякозябры, как и в случае с любым растровым изображением. Векторный редактор при загрузке svgz производит обратную кодировку в SVG/

Comment: Ну, растровым он не становится, конечно, но бинарным да :) Тут [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733020/svgz-file-format) пишут, что all browsers support SVGZ when served with the proper HTTP headers. А [также](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676412/can-one-create-a-svgz-file-which-displays-directly-in-a-browser), что decompression that's not supported by the file protocol by browsers В общем, с тем же успехом можно включить в настройках веб-сервера gzip на лету для обычных текстовых svg. Но можно хранить в заранее сжатом виде и добавить тип: `AddType image/svg+xml svgz`

Comment: `data-attr не принадлежат пространству имен SVG, поэтому были удалены` Как я вижу, 
svgomg опенсорсный, то есть можно сделать форк и изменить немного правила сжатия, если такое по силам, конечно)

Comment: @ДавидМанжула Не, с svgomg всё ок, атрибуты не он грохнул, но не суть.

Answer (score 1):

### Ещё одна идея с использованием viewBox

Управляя размером viewBox в шапке SVG файла, можно показывать небольшую часть огромного SVG файла. С помощью выбора значений viewBox возникает возможность  разделить svg canvas на отдельные, прямоугольные участки, части карты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### *Немного теории*

**viewport** - это область видимости, часть бесконечного SVG холста, которую видит пользователь на дисплее своего гаджета. Размеры viewport, допустим; - width="250" height="250" задает автор файла SVG с началом координат в левом верхнем углу.

**viewBox** - в качестве примера - `viewBox="0 0 250 250"`  - это виртуальная, прямоугольная область просмотра, которую пользователь не видит, но от которой зависит какая часть бесконечного полотна SVG будет показана на дисплее пользователя. Кроме того последние два атрибута viewBox отвечают за масштабирование изображения. Подробнее [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=5). Если ширина и высота `viewport = viewBox` равны, то масштаб будет один к одному.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

За перемещение viewBox отвечают первые два параметра `viewBox="min-x min-y width height"`

Перемещая viewBox можно показывать разные, небольшие участки большого SVG файла.

Я создал небольшую демонстрационную программу, которая показывает процесс, как с помощью изменения параметров `min-x`и `min-y` viewBox`a можно выбирать небольшие участки большого SVG файла.

*Кнопка **Start** - для начала работы демонстрационной программы*

```html
<style>
.container {
width:45vw;
height:45vh;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 600 360" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    
 <defs>
    <g id="canvas-svg" stroke-width="2px">  
      <g id="canvas-frame1">
       <rect id="v-port1" x="25" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue"   fill="yellowgreen" /> 
        <text id="t-port1" x="75" y="255" style="font-size: 16pt;">1 </text>
        <text  x="26" y="303" > 0 </text>
     </g>           
      <g id="canvas-frame2">        
            <rect id="v-port2" x="135" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue"  fill="dodgerblue" /> 
            <text id="t-port2" x="185" y="255" style="font-size: 16pt;">2 </text>
            <text  x="136" y="303" > 1168 </text>
     </g>         
      <g id="canvas-frame3">        
            <rect id="v-port3" x="245" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue"  fill="crimson"  /> 
            <text id="t-port3" x="295" y="255" style="font-size: 16pt;">3 </text>
            <text  x="246" y="303" > 2336 </text>
      </g>
          <g id="canvas-frame4">        
            <rect id="v-port4" x="355" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue"  fill="orange" /> 
            <text id="t-port4" x="405" y="255" style="font-size: 16pt;">4 </text>
            <text  x="356" y="303" > 3504 </text>
         </g>
           <g id="canvas-frame5">       
            <rect id="v-port5" x="465" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue" stroke-width="1px" fill="yellow" /> 
            <text id="t-port5" x="515" y="255" style="font-size: 16pt;">5 </text>
            <text  x="466" y="303" > 4672 </text>
           </g>   
     </g>
        
 </defs>
 
  <g id="first-rect">
       <rect  x="25" y="25" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue" stroke-width="1px" fill="yellowgreen" /> 
        <text  x="75" y="85" style="font-size: 16pt;">1 </text>
        <text  x="26" y="135" > 0 </text>
     </g>           
           
    <use xlink:href ="#canvas-svg" x="0" y="0"> </use>
    
     <g id="viewBox1">
     <rect id="v-box" x="25" y="200" width="110" height="110" stroke="skyblue" stroke-width="5px" fill="none" />
         <text id="t-port1" x="45" y="225" style="font-size: 16pt; fill:blue;">viewBox </text>   
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="startButton.click+0.5s" end="stopButton.click" dur="20s" from="0 0" to="440 0" repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>
     </g>   
    <use xlink:href ="#canvas-svg" x="0" y="0">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="startButton.click+0.5s" end="stopButton.click" dur="20s" from="0 -170" to="-440 -170" repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" />
      </use>
        
 <g fill="#E5E5E5" stroke="#E5E5E5">
     <rect  x="135" y="0" width="465" height="195"    />   
      <rect  x="0" y="0" width="25" height="195"    />   
      <rect  x="0" y="0" width="135" height="30"    />   
      <rect  x="25" y="135" width="135" height="60" />   
      <rect  x="0" y="315" width="600" height="85"  />   
      <rect  x="0" y="195" width="25" height="120"  />
      <rect  x="575" y="195" width="25" height="120" />
 </g> 
  
  <g stroke-width="1px" stroke-dasharray = "5 5"> 
    <line x1="25" y1="140" x2="25" y2="195" stroke="blue"  />
     <line x1="135" y1="140" x2="135" y2="195" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1px"  />
  </g>      
       <g style="font-size: 16pt; fill:blue;">
        <text  x="45" y="170"  > viewport </text> 
         <text  x="15" y="20" style="font-size: 14pt;"> Дисплей гаджета  </text>
            <text  x="230" y="90" style="font-size: 40pt; fill:#1E90FF"> canvas SVG </text> 
       </g> 
    
    <g id="startButton">
        <rect  x="520" y="325" rx="8" ry="8" width="60" height="20" fill="#58AE2A" />
        <text  x="550" y="340" font-size="16" font-weight="bold" font-family="Arial" text-anchor="middle" 
        fill="white" >Start</text>
    </g>
            <g id="stopButton">
                <rect  x="450" y="325" rx="8" ry="8" width="60" height="20" fill="#1E90FF" />
                <text  x="480" y="340" font-size="16" font-weight="bold" font-family="Arial" text-anchor="middle" 
                fill="white" >Stop</text>
            </g>    
    
    </svg>
</div>
```

```
<svg id="svgMap" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="250" 
   height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
```

Вот так перемещая viewBox мы можем получить любой фрагмент карты на дисплее гаджета.

Первый фрагмент карты левый верхний прямоугольник. См. всю карту выше

В обозначении -**A1** - Буквы - ряды | цифры - столбцы

A1 `viewBox="0 0 250 250"` ------------- A2 `viewBox="250 0 250 250"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

B1 `viewBox="0 250 250 250"` ------------- B2 `viewBox="250 250 250 250"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, Александр. Фундаментальная проблема в том, что последовательность записи данных в файле не зависит от близости точек на плоскости, и чтобы двигать viewBox по теоретически бесконечному холсту, весь холст со всеми объектами на нем должен быть загружен в память целиком. Это ограничивает применение SVG в картографии, в частности мой проект потенциально охватывает только центр Ростова-на-Дону. Не первое место встает производительность масштабирования и прокрутки. Пока лучшим решением оказалось D3 Zooming API (там используется `transform` для корневого элемента `g`, включающего всю карту)

Comment: @Alexey Vladimirov я искренне пытался тебе помочь в решении вопроса и проделал много черновой работы. И теперь, по крайней мере мы  знаем с тобой в каком направлении стоит копать, а какие направления решения вопроса будут неэффективны.  Удачи тебе и успехов в твоем проекте.