# Как сменить курсор внутри use?

Tags: css, svg

Левый круг является тегом `circle`, а правый - тегом `use`, использующим левый круг.

Как сделать, чтобы только у левого круга был `cursor: pointer`, а у правого - обычная стрелка?

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { display: grid; margin: 0; }
svg { width: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: auto; }

circle { cursor: pointer; }
use, use circle { cursor: auto; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 19 10">
  <circle id="smth" r="4" fill="blue" />
  <use xlink:href="#smth" x="9" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно прокинуть значение через css-переменные:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { display: grid; margin: 0; }
svg { width: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: auto; }

svg { --cursor: pointer; }
use { --cursor: auto; }
circle { cursor: var(--cursor); }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 19 10">
  <circle id="smth" r="4" fill="blue" />
  <use xlink:href="#smth" x="9" />
</svg>
```

PS: Не знаю, может есть и способы лучше.

Answer (score 3):

Используем `<use>`? Тогда логично использовать и `<defs>`:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { display: grid; margin: 0; }
svg { width: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: auto; }

use:nth-of-type(1) { cursor: default; }
use:nth-of-type(2) { cursor: pointer; }
use:nth-of-type(3) { cursor: crosshair; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 19 10">
  <defs>
    <circle id="smth" r="2" fill="blue" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#smth" x="0" />
  <use xlink:href="#smth" x="4" />
  <use xlink:href="#smth" x="8" />
</svg>
```

К тому же, не стоить указывать параметры в атрибутах, а после пытаться "перебить" их свойствами CSS. Если и указывать атрибуты, то только те, которые статичны или изменяются скриптами.

При правильной разметке SVG (референсы, группировка) все стили CSS работают, как ожидается:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { display: grid; margin: 0; }
svg { width: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: auto; }

.red use { y: -2px; fill: #f00; }
.blue use { y: 2px; fill: #00f; }

.red use:nth-of-type(1) { cursor: default; }
.red use:nth-of-type(2) { cursor: pointer; }
.red use:nth-of-type(3) { cursor: crosshair; }

.cell { cursor: cell; }
.help { cursor: help; }
.zoom { cursor: zoom-in; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 19 10">
  <defs>
    <circle id="smth" r="2" />
  </defs>
  <g class="red">
    <use xlink:href="#smth" x="0" />
    <use xlink:href="#smth" x="4" />
    <use xlink:href="#smth" x="8" />
  </g>
  <g class="blue">
    <use xlink:href="#smth" x="0" class="cell" />
    <use xlink:href="#smth" x="4" class="help" />
    <use xlink:href="#smth" x="8" class="zoom" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Интересный вариант.

Comment: @UModeL Узнал кое-что новое, благодаря твоей опечатке  вместо `<defs>` написано `<def>` и вроде как работает это. Работает, скрывая круг до вызова по ID. Но если написать вместо `<defs>` =>`<d>` тоже будет работать/  Но начинаются отличия - в FF, как и положено, останавливается выполнение после первого ошибочного тега - Выводится только первый ряд. Chrome жрёт эту ошибку и выводит всё (оба ряда)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: была свободная минута и доступ в сеть. Кодил второпях, чтобы развеяться. Уточни пожалуйста, что значит "... до вызова по ID."

Comment: @UModeL `<defs>` скрывает <circle> ` до вызова по `id` =>`<use xlink:href="#smth" x="0" />` Обычное явление для SVG - парсер svg останавливает выполнение после ошибки, но парсер HTML пропускает ошибку и идёт дальше. Если будет время разберу все нюансы в отдельном ответе. Действительно интересная ситуация

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: SVG в Chrome подхватывает (или приводит) единицы измерения, в FF нужно указывать явно, если значения находятся в CSS, а не в атрибутах. То есть, не `y: 2`, а `y: 2px`.

Answer (score 3):

Можно обернуть круг в группу и применять курсор к ней:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { display: grid; margin: 0; }
svg { width: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: auto; }

g { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 19 10">
  <g>
    <circle id="smth" r="4" fill="blue" />
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#smth" x="9" />
</svg>
```

Comment: ♦  Я не понимаю, что ты хотел продемонстрировать данным примером. Одно из частных решений, где на одном круге есть курсор `g { cursor: pointer; }`  заданный CSS, а на другом круге курсор по умолчанию?  Всё правильно, курсор не наследуется, так как после `<use>` объект попадает в shadow DOM и свойства CSS родителя не передается дочерней копии и остается значением для `<circle>` по умолчанию -   `cursor: default;`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, да всё понятно, но почему-то я сначала додумался до css-переменных. Так что пусть уж будет, раз ответы собираем.

Comment: да,  ответ с CSS переменными, был самым универсальным, кроссбраузерным ответом, так как CSS переменные, имеют наивысший приоритет (computed styles)  Вот табличка иерархии стилей, в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1380959/28748)